# Remove CR and LF in Linux

Tags: sed

How can I remove with sed all CR and LF from text file (join lines)

Answer (score 6):

```
tr -d '\n\r' < file
```

Comment: the obviously easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\r` and `\n`, depending on your OS.

`\r\n` works on windows, `\n` works on most *nixes, but replacing that with a blank string should merge your lines just fine.

Comment: The question is quite `sed` specific (tag and title). Learning simple patterns or recipes for sed, helps develop an understanding to handle more complex cases.

Comment: @mctylr; So? Regex is regex, whether you're using it in sed or perl. Just pointing the op at the pattern they want to match will help them a lot more than a copy&paste command, imo.

Comment: See page 23 of Mastering Regular Expressions http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528126/preview or "Different Regular Expression Engines" in http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html or http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php

Comment: @mctylr; I of course realise the differences in implementation, however matching *a single, known character* doesn't change between implementations. \r\n is \r\n regardless of who's asking, this is not something under the control of how the engine is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dennis Williamson ... here is another alternative:

```
perl -0pe 's/[\r\n]//g' < in > out
```

Why do so many questions include "with sed"?  I do use sed, but I don't fight its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

On an Unix/Linux system I believe this will work for you. I tested it with GNU sed, but I don't think this is using GNU extensions.

```
sed -e :a -e '/$/N; s/\r\n//; ta;' <in.txt >out.txt
```

Comment: If you change it so the cr and nl are in square brackets then it will work even if one or the other is missing or they are in the opposite order: `[\r\n]`

Comment: Yes, so it depends if one cares to remove all `\r` and `\n` characters, or only `\r\n` "pairs". Different cases may have different answers. But very good point, thanks.

Comment: Almost incredible that in all this time no-one has suggested sed | sed as a solution. Nobody discusses the ctrl-V ctrl-M keystroke requirement (ala vi) ? I suppose the old hands know and stop asking...